# Calculus: Problem on two continuously differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$f$ and $g$ are two continuously differentiable functions on $[1,\infty]$ with $f(1)=1=g(1)$ and $\frac{{g'\left( x \right)}}{{f'\left( x \right)}} \geqslant f\left( x \right)$. Prove that $2g\left( x \right) \geqslant {f^2}\left( x \right) + 1$.

Comment: Use $(f^2)' = 2ff'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is wrong when $f'(x)<0$. Consider the example $$f(x):=2-x,\qquad g(x):=-{2\over3}x^3+2x^2-3x+{8\over3}\ .$$
Then $f(1)=g(1)=1$ and $$g'(x)=-1-2(x-1)^2\leq -1\leq x-2\qquad(x\geq1)\ .$$
It follows that
$${g'(x)\over f'(x)}={g'(x)\over-1}\geq 2-x=f(x)\ ,$$
which proves that $f$ and $g$ together fulfill your conditions. But $g(x)<0$ for large $x$, and this violates your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f'>0$, by multiplying ${{g'(x)}\over {f'(x)}}$ by $f'(x)$, we have:

$g'(x)\geq f(x)f'(x)$. Thus $\int_1^xg'(x)dx\geq\int_1^xf'(x)f(x)dx$. We deduce that $g(x)-g(1)\geq (1/2)f^2(x) -(f(1))^2/2)$. We deduce $g(x)-1\geq (1/2)f(x)^2-1/2$. We deduce that $2g(x)\geq f(x)^2+1$.

Comment: This demands that $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: After integration we get $g\left( x \right) \geqslant \frac{{{f^2}\left( x \right)}}{2} + c$ and putting $x=1$ we get $c \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$. Then how possibly the inequality can be shown?

Comment: Do you kkow what is the value of $\int_1^xh'(x)dx$